# to insert new div block using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to insert new div block if I click insert button.But, when I search in internet , I found the ways.I used one ways.But it used constant div block .I want to use only id to call that new div block and if I click remove option ,I want to delete it .`"<div class="main-block"></div>"` that place, I want to call id to show that main block.How can I do that ?

Please help me.

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
    $('.block:last').before('<div class="main-block"><div class="main-block"></div><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>');
});
$('.main-block').on('click','.remove',function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="col-md-2  main-title">
    <b>Language</b>
    <label class="title">Japan </label><br>
    <label class="title">Chinese </label><br>
    <label class="title">English </label><br>
    <label class="title">Korea </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4  main-title">
    <b style="margin-left:40px;">Name</b>
    <select class="selectbox" name="select1" id="select1">
      <option value="1">Business Center</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectbox" name="select2" id="select2">
      <option value="1">Chinese</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectbox" name="select3" id="select3">
      <option value="1">English Center</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectbox" name="select4" id="select4">
      <option value="1">Korea Center</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 main-title">
   <b style="margin-left:40px;">Alias Name</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box" />
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <span class="add">Add Option</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```js
$(function(){
  $('.add').click(function() {
     $("#main-block").show();
  });
$('.remove').on('click',function() {
  $("#main-block").hide();
});
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#main-block {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="col-md-2  main-title">
    <b>Language</b>
    <label class="title">Japan </label><br>
    <label class="title">Chinese </label><br>
    <label class="title">English </label><br>
    <label class="title">Korea </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4  main-title">
    <b style="margin-left:40px;">Name</b>
    <select class="selectbox" name="select1" id="select1">
      <option value="1">Business Center</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectbox" name="select2" id="select2">
      <option value="1">Chinese</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectbox" name="select3" id="select3">
      <option value="1">English Center</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selectbox" name="select4" id="select4">
      <option value="1">Korea Center</option>
      <option value="2">Option 1</option>
      <option value="3">Option 2</option>
      <option value="4">Option 3</option>
      <option value="5">Option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 main-title">
   <b style="margin-left:40px;">Alias Name</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-box" />
  </div>
  <div class="main-block" id="main-block"><div class="main-block"></div><span class="remove">Remove Option</span></div>
  <div class="block">
    <span class="add">Add Option</span>
  </div>
</div>
```